# How to get Xorg to work well with Intel Q35 on OpenSolaris?

Tags: x11, intel, opensolaris

OpenSolaris doesn't seem to support the Intel 82Q35 chipset. This is translated into slow Xorg whose performance degrades with time and is not usable at all even doing a ls on a fullscreen gnome console terminal.

I notice that a huge amount of memory (>400Mb) is used by Xorg process and gnome (>100Mb per gnome app). Once I switched to vesa it all become more reasonable Xorg (90Mb). But sometimes with more GUI intensive apps the UI becomes slow.

Is there any alternatives to make it more responsive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenSolaris ships with the [open source Xorg & DRI drivers for Intel chipsets](http://www.opensolaris.org/os/project/intelgraphics/) that Intel helps make sure work well on OpenSolaris, and they list Q35 on the supported list, so it should work.   The developers respond to [bug reports](http://defect.opensolaris.org) or posts in the [xwin-discuss mailing list/web forum](http://www.opensolaris.org/os/community/x_win/discussions) on opensolaris.org.